# OpenCV C++ detectMultiScale crashes UE4 - Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, opencv, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create an OpenCV plugin for Unreal Engine 4 to detect faces, but when the code reaches the detectMultiScale function I get this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD4F34FF1B (UE4Editor-Core.dll) in
>   UE4Editor-Win64-DebugGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0x0000000000000010.

I am using OpenCV version 4.1.0  with VS2017. I also tried with version 3.4.7 of OpenCV, but having the same issue.

This is my function that gets the webcam input and renders it in UE4:
In the constructor:

```
if (!face_cascade.load("C:\\models\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); }
```

And the function:

```
void AWebcamReader::UpdateTexture()
{
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    cv::Mat frame_gray;


    //cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    if (isStreamOpen && frame.data)
    {
        cv::cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | cv::CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5);
            ellipse(frame, center, cv::Size(faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);

            cv::Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]);


        }

        // Copy Mat data to Data array
        for (int y = 0; y < VideoSize.Y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < VideoSize.X; x++)
            {
                int i = x + (y * VideoSize.X);
                Data[i].B = frame.data[i * 3 + 0];
                Data[i].G = frame.data[i * 3 + 1];
                Data[i].R = frame.data[i * 3 + 2];
            }
        }

        // Update texture 2D
        UpdateTextureRegions(VideoTexture, (int32)0, (uint32)1, VideoUpdateTextureRegion, (uint32)(4 * VideoSize.X), (uint32)4, (uint8*)Data.GetData(), false);
    }
}
```

If I comment out the detectMultiScale function, the plugin runs without a problem and I see the webcam input rendered correctly.

The Exception gets called on this line in VT2.cpp (VT2 is the project name)

```
IMPLEMENT_PRIMARY_GAME_MODULE( FDefaultGameModuleImpl, VT2, "VT2" );
```

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your execution go until `detectMultiScale` method, it means no issue with Opencv module inclusion. But Which libs did you include while loading Opencv ? ( Modules in Opencv can be separated into several DLLs, not always the big opencv_worldXXX.dll ).
Did you rebuild opencv with your visual studio ? Don't know about opencv4 but not sure CV3 give the vs2017 libs.

Comment: I included the opencv_worldXXX.dll. I tried it with the opencv installer that comes already compiled, and I also tried it with my own compiled version of opencv, same result both times

Comment: I thought at first that the CascadeClassifier wasn't in the opencv_world.dll because it has been necessary in olders version to build opencv_contrib to add `objdetect` module. But it seems today its included in the libs. Did you have the 'BUILD_opencv_objdetect' checkbox checked in CMake when you build it from Sources ? Did you test that your build is ok by launching the objdetect samples ? If that works outside of UE4 it may be a bad inclusion or libraries loading imo.
Can you check if the dlls used and loaded by UE4 are the sames that the one in your PATH var ?

Comment: I know this was a while ago but was this issue resolved?

Comment: @JadenTravnik no